# Sequence whose translations contain a bounded amount of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ given by $a_n=n!+2$, its "translations" $a_n+k$ contain only finitely many primes for all $k\ge0$ since for $n\ge k+2$ we have that $k+2$ divides $n!+k+2$.

We construct a new sequence $\{b_j\}_{j\in\Bbb N}$ defined as $b_j=\text{number of primes in }(a_n+j)$.

Is $b_j$ a bounded sequence? If not is there a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ whose translations contain only finitely many primes and whose associated sequence $\{b_j\}_{j\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded?

Comment: It's not hard to show that the set $\{a_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ cannot have bounded gaps, since then some finite set of translates of the $\{a_n\}$ will cover cofinitely many naturals, and therefore cofinitely many primes, so one of these translates must have infinitely many primes.

Of course this still leaves the problem wide open...

Comment: If this were the case, wouldn't it give you lots of counter-examples to the first Hardy–Littlewood conjecture ?